# How can I overwrite an object in R if I only know the name of the object as a character string?

Tags: r, object, reference, pass-by-name

In my R function, I am dealing with a character string containing the name of an object that is sitting somewhere in the workspace. I would like to overwrite the object (e.g., convert the object to a matrix).

However, I only know the name of the object as a character string, and I don't have the object reference. I know I can convert the character string to an object reference either by using the `get(x)` function (where `x` is the string referring to the object), or by something like `eval(as.name(x))`. However, this works only for accessing the object, not for overwriting the object.

How can I achieve this? Here is some code:

```
myvector <- 1:5              # my object
x <- "myvector"              # text representation of the object
get(x) <- as.matrix(get(x))  # my first attempt
eval(as.name(x)) <- as.matrix(eval(as.name(x)))  # second attempt
```

Note that the first line is not part of the function from which I want to overwrite this object in the workspace, so I cannot just write `myvector <- as.matrix(myvector)`.

Comment: do you look for `?assign`?: `assign(x= "myvector" ,newvalue)`

Comment: Cool, that was much easier than I thought! Thanks very much! So the solution is: `assign(x, as.matrix(get(x)))`

Comment: I suspect that whatever you are doing with that should probably be done in a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to assign by name a global variable within a function. Why? Should avoid to manipulate global variable and as said in the comment should exist better manner to deal with your problem and avoid global variable side effect.
You should use `assign` to change value by name. By default, it changes value in the current environment(local),  So you should also set in which environment your variable is defined. Something like this :

```
 assign( x , as.matrix(get(x)),envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Or , tell `assign` to search until it encounters the variable :

```
 assign( x , as.matrix(get(x)),inherits=TRUE)
```

#### EDIT better solution

1. Return the new value and assign it later in the global environment

   ```
   assign( x , function(x){....})
   ```
2. If the variable is kind of global setting you can define an environment where your define myvector.

   ```
   myoptions <- new.env()
   myoptions$myvalue <- 1:5
   function(x){ assign(x,newvalue,myoptions )}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not very familiar with environments. It would be OK if the object was copied from the global environment to the function and overwritten only inside the function. Or if a new object with the same name was created locally within the function (instead of overwriting it).

Comment: @SpammerSlammer Better is to return the new value and assign it later in the global environment.

Comment: @SpammerSlammer you can see my edit. I suggest a couple of solutions.

Comment: I don't really understand your edits, but your original solution seems to work for me. I need a new object in the local environment (that is, inside the function only) which has the same name as the object in the global environment but to which I can assign a new value. The local object is only used for estimations within the function, but it is crucial that it has the same name as the global object. So I think this can be achieved using `assign(x, as.matrix(get(x)))` inside my function without any additional option. (At least it seemed to work when I tried it.)

Comment: You said: "it is crucial that it has the same name as the global object" ? why? poor design here!

Comment: Because: There is a function contained in a package which has a formula syntax where elements can be functions that need to be evaluated. Example: `y ~ object1 + doSomething(object2, arg = someArgument)`. I don't have access to the functions contained in that package, but my task is to write a function that creates a formula like the one shown here. So in my function, the user should hand over a formula, then I should transform the objects from this formula locally (thus I need the object references), then I should reassemble the formula and hand it over to the estimation in the other package.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33087/discussion-between-agstudy-and-spammerslammer)